# Losing Canvas scrollbars when wrapping canvas into a grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, grid

This issue occurs in a WPF application.

The project is using a ContentControl that loads a Canvas and draws in this canvas whatever needs to be drawn.
This canvas has vertical and horizontal scrollbars.

Now I need to wrap this ContentControl into a grid, next to a GroupBox.

So I replaced:

```
 <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Viewer.Content}" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
```

with:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Load_Grid" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="DarkGray" Opacity="0.9">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" 
              x:Name="Legend_Inserts_Status"
              Header="Legend"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              BorderBrush="#FF4EA8DE"
              FontSize="10"
              Foreground="#FF436EFF"
              Width="80"
              Visibility="{Binding DisplayLegend,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
        <Grid>
            <!--My groupbox content here -->
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Viewer.Content}" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

When doing this, my new GroupBox renders properly, the canvas is still displayed but without its horizontal and vertical scrollbars.
Is there any reason why?

Actually, even if I comment the GroupBox, the scroll bars are removed. So it seems that removing the scroll bars comes from wrapping the ContentControl into the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because you have your Column's set to an `Auto` `Width` which by definition allows the children of that column to consume whatever space required and size to the columns content.

By doing so you're negating any boundary to invoke the `ScrollViewer` built into the `ContentControl` template. Basically because it has nothing telling it "Hey! You're only allowed to be x,y size and if you go over that size then we need scrollbars." is a plain way of putting it. So you're going to need to set a `MaxWidth` or use a `*` or something that will invoke that boundary for the `ScrollViewer` to kick in.

Comment: Thx a ton for the explanation Chris.
Knowing that the first column (gridview) will have a Visibility as true or collapsed. So I suppose I cannot use Width = "N*" .
Is there a way to have the ScrollVewer to correctly render (showing its scrollbars) and auto adapt to the gridview's Visibility?

Comment: @A.D. I see a Grid, but not a GridView. If the one column has content with Visibility toggling give it the `Auto` width so it will collapse when it's children aren't present. Then give the other column `*` where you scroll-able content lives and it will invoke the scrolls when they're necessary.

Comment: Wonderful.
By setting first column's width as auto and second columns width as 1* it worked just fine.
Thx a ton Chris, you rock :) And sorry for dummy question.

Comment: @A.D. No worries man, we've all been there. Glad you got a remedy. :)